# how to use Classification functions in support vector machines about svc.predict?

Tags: svm

it's output all '1' or '0' with using svc.predict(x_test)

I want to get a normal classification result to keep my program running

```py
def svm_predict(x_data, y_data, Test_size, Random_state):  #svm预测结果并返回一个不同核的最高值
    y_data = np.ravel(y_data)
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = ts(x_data, y_data, test_size=Test_size, random_state=Random_state)

    # kernel = 'rbf'
    clf_rbf = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma='auto')
    clf_rbf.fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_rbf_predict = clf_rbf.predict(x_test)
    score_rbf = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_rbf_predict)

    # kernel = 'linear'
    clf_linear = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', gamma='auto')
    clf_linear.fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_linear_predict = clf_linear.predict(x_test)
    score_linear = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_linear_predict)

    # kernel = 'poly'
    clf_poly = svm.SVC(kernel='poly', gamma='auto')
    clf_poly.fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_ploy_predict = clf_poly.predict(x_test)
    score_poly = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_ploy_predict)
    return max(score_rbf, score_linear, score_poly)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the result of predict should be used as the parameter of roc_auc_score, but I'm not sure whether predict_proba or decision_function should be used, it seems to be ok. In addition, I have seen the annotation you wrote, I am a Chinese, I can discuss it

Comment: 上面那个值恒为一个结果的问题是数据的问题，你说的那个参数为什么不能使用y_predict

Comment: roc_auc_score需要置信度，或者说是概率（这是scikitlearn里写的，也是周志华那本机器学习说的），如果直接给分类器的预测结果，那么对于能够给出置信度的分类器而言，这是不合适的，这样不能正确评估出分类器的泛化能力@shangwen song